# Program to write on PDF

Tags: windows-8.1, pdf

I am new to SU, so this is my first question.

Do you know a program with which I can write directly on the screen?

I am not having in mind one that just fills in text, but one that you can draw or write freely on it. I was wondering, since my professor is using such to draw examples on the PDF slides, what it could be?

I am a Windows 8.1 64-bit user.

Comment: why the downvotes? could you also comment why?

Comment: Asking for direction to a program is off topic here.

Comment: The question is not clear and seem to have on the first view nothing to do with PDF. Also the question should be placed at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: there is a lot of "presentation" software out there that will do overlays over any screen your viewing, it comes free with vaious presentation input devices. highlighting, stamping circling pointing and drawing. In those cases it is not always drawing on the programs itself, but on a screen grab or overlay that is then displayed, all automatically to scribble apon.

Comment: I think i've written on PDFs with Acrobat IX or maybe XI   I doubt they removed features.. Maybe even Acrobat reader..  Here is a video of it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxbnMDWstJo

Comment: Why don't you just ask the professor?

Answer (score 2):

Acrobat XI can do it. I've done it or something like it before, there's a feature called annotations.

Here is a youtube video of drawing on a PDF

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxbnMDWstJo

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if it's a trial program or not.. to what extent it's free.

Answer (score 1):

The first program that google gave me for this is

https://www.pdfescape.com/ - this is an online tool that will let You do the trick.

[image]

There is also

[Nitro Reader 3](https://www.gonitro.com/pdf-reader) - is also looks like a nice tool, but I am not sure that the free version lets You to edit. I am sure that the paid version does, it looks nice with all it's features like [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), and the GUI also looks great, but I find it a bit too expensive.

[Word Processor and PDF Editor](http://www.ableword.net/) - also looks a fine tool, but I guess it doesn't let You do all the fancy stuff only text editing and some basic features. It is totally free even for commercial use.

I will update my answer with more research results soon.

EDIT:
Here is a top 3 pdf editor:
http://www.neowin.net/news/top-3-free-programs-to-edit-convert-or-create-pdf-files

You can also try to ask this question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your professor might be using LaTeX with a beamer template.

If you want you could use Open Office to create your slides and just save as a pdf.

Comment: actually I want to write on already created pdf files.